# How do i implement registration Class (with OOPS concepts ) in PHP?

Tags: php, class, registration, oop

I am creating a register/signup page in PHP, so I create a class `class.register.php`
as I'm implementing first time complete class basis way in PHP and also using `PDO`. Please suggest me how to make worthy class with optimized way. Below is is my class:

#### class.register.php

```
class registration 
{
    private $_confirm = 0;
    public $post_data = array();
    private $db;
    protected $db_name ='db_movies';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass ='keshav';
    
    
    function __construct($post_data)
    {
            $this->post_data = array_map('trim',$post_data);
            $this->db_connect();
            return $this->post_data;
        
    }
    
    protected function db_connect()
    {
        try {
                $this->db =  new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);     
                return $this->db;
            } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
                print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                die();
            }
    }
    
    public function setPostIntoSession()
    {
        return $_SESSION['post_data']=$this->post_data;             
    }

    public function checkEmailInDB()
    {
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_user WHERE email_address = :email");
      $stmt->bindParam(':email',$this->post_data['email_address'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
      return $result;
    }
    
    public function insertIntoDB()
    {
      $qry = "INSERT INTO tbl_user SET 
                                            email_address = :email,
                                            first_name = :first_name,
                                            middle_initial = :middle_name,
                                            last_name = :last_name,
                                            title =:title,
                                            organization = : organization,
                                            primary_phone =:primary_phone,
                                            secondary_phone =:secondary_phone,
                                            website =:website,
                                            how_found =:found ";
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare($qry);
      $stmt->bindParam(':email',$this->post_data['email_address'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':first_name',$this->post_data['first_name'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':middle_name',$this->post_data['middle_initial'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':last_name',$this->post_data['last_name'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':title',$this->post_data['title'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':organization',$this->post_data['organization'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':primary_phone',$this->post_data['primary_phone'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':secondary_phone',$this->post_data['secondary_phone'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':website',$this->post_data['website'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':found',$this->post_data['how_found'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
      return $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

here i m using above class

#### signup.php

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start();
include_once ('includes/class.register.php');
$register = new registration($_POST);
$fine = true;

$register->setPostIntoSession();
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($register);

if(count($_POST)>0){    
    
        if($register->checkEmailInDB())
        {
            echo $_SESSION['error'] ='Sorry,given e-mail address already exists.';
            $fine = false;
        }
        if ($register->post_data['pswd'] !== $register->post_data['confirm_pswd'])
        { 
            echo $_SESSION['error'] ='Sorry,both password are not matching';
            $fine = false;          
        }
        else 
        {
            $register->insertIntoDB();
        }
}
if($fine == false ) 
{
    //header("location:signup.php");
    //exit();
}
else
{
    echo "All izz Well";
}

//$register->watch($register);
?>
```

I think I'm doing this in very length way, please suggest me which function I should implement in class.

Comment: Please suggest the better optimized and proper way to implement class

Comment: don't forget to mark as solved if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: THIS IS MY OPINION.
Well I for one Like to code following the MVC pattern, and with that also proper inheritance of classes. Why do I say this, its because you seem to have many things mixed up in there ( although the code is correct). For me the registration is more of a process than a model object so having a model class for it is not ideal.

This is how I would optimize this:
First create a generic DB class that handles the login/conection and query execution.
then when creating a model, extend from this class so you can use those methods.
for instance, for registration, it would be to register a user, so supposing you have a user table, you create a user class that extends db. In that user class you can handle the input validation and inserting into DB.
example:

```
<?php
class ent_db
{
    private $DBUserName;
    private $DBPassword;
    private $DBHost;
    private $DBConnection = null;
    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->DBUserName = config::$dbuser;
        $this->DBPassword = config::$dbpass;
        $this->DBHost = config::$dbhost;
    }
    function executeQuery($sql)
    {
        return mysql_query($sql,$this->getConnection());

    }
     function getConnection()
    {
        if ($this->DBConnection===null)
            return mysql_connect($this->DBHost, $this->DBUserName,$this->DBPassword);
        else
            return $this->DBConnection;
    }
    function close()
    {
        if ($this->DBConnection!== null)
        {
            mysql_close($this->DBConnection);
            $this->DBConnection = null;
        }
    }
    function getAffectedRows()
{
    return mysql_affected_rows($this->getConnection());
}
function getAll($sql){

    $ret = $this->executeQuery($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($ret) !== 0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret))
        {
            $return[]=$row;
        }

        $this->close();
        return $return;

        }else
        {   
            $this->close();
            return false;
    }

        }
}
?>
```

then you can have your user class ( here its structure)

```
    <?php
class ent_structures extends ent_db
{
function getStructures($sort=null)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM crm.structure WHERE disabled = 0";
    $sql.=($sort!==null)?" ORDER BY $sort":"";
    $ret = $this->executeQuery($sql);
    //or return $this->getAll();
.
.
.    
.
```

this would clear things up a bit and allow you not to rewrite the code to connect to the DB etc on each time.
Then I'd use controllers to handle to flow for instance a registerController to handle the registering etc..
Using helper classes to handle repetitive tasks that don't fall into either category.

Well i hope you get the idea.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i m using PDO.. i just want to know which function should i derive in my class

Comment: You could be using smoke signal storage and this would still be relevant. In your DB class you code all that is needed to make the connection and queries to the DB server, then on your classes that inherit, you add the specific code to that class ( or model object).  Just change my mysql code to your PDO and give it a try. you just have to add the pdo specific code there. this was just to illustrate the tecnique I consider proper in this case